# MIPS and how to store the correct amount of numbers

Tags: assembly, architecture, mips, cpu-registers

```
.data
price:    .word   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
str1:   .asciiz   " Please enter the number of items you are entering:   "
str2:    .asciiz     " Please enter the price of each item : "
str3:    .asciiz     " The total is: "
.text


.main:
        li    $s0,0        #counter
        li    $s1,20        #20

        li    $v0,4        #print string
        la    $a0,str1    #load address
        syscall            #output


        li $v0,5
        syscall
        add    $s2,$0,$v0    # put the number of integers need to inputed to $v0

        ble    $s2, $s1,loop1    


        li    $v0,4        #print string
        la    $a0,str3    #load address
        syscall            #output


loop1:

        li    $v0,4        #print string
        la    $a0,str2    #load address
        syscall            #output

        li $v0,5
        syscall
        add    $s2,$0,$v0    # put the number of integers needed to inputed to  $s2
```

j loop1

What I'm getting messed up on is that it asks how many items I enter and say for example I enter 3, and it only stores 2 numbers. What can I do , so that the screen outputs ALL of my numbers onto the screen? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _"store"_, because nowhere in your program do you store any of the numbers you read to memory. If you want to do something N number of times, write a loop. Your `loop1` label is currently not part of a loop because you never jump back to it. Also, you should explicitly terminate your program using system call 10.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is homework

Comment: That's your problem Johan

Comment: Good point thanks Michael ! I guess I didn't proofread it yesterday

Comment: I actually got my question answered by a tutor already. Nevermind. Thanks again folks!!